# Google maps api as a partial view within asp.net mvc5 application

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have, in my asp.net mvc5 application, this partial  view :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBCVSBoBAUjAfb-Pfx_qq0ZKUHCitbzsl4&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

    function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
             (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            { types: ['geocode'] });

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }

    function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementById(component).value = '';
            document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
            }
        }
    }

    function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var geolocation = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };

                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: geolocation,
                    radius: position.coords.accuracy
                });
                autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
            });
        }
    }
</script>

<html>
<body>
    <p><input type="text" onfocus="geolocate()" placeholder="Taper l'adresse" id="autocomplete" name="nomlieu_adress" class="fiche" style="width:500px"></p>

    <p>
        <label style="width:90px">Avenue</label><input type="text" id="street_number" name="avenue_adress" style="width:160px; " class="fiche" />
        <label style="width:90px">Rue</label><input type="text" id="route" name="rue_adress" style="width:157px" class="fiche" />
    </p>

    <p> <label style="width:90px">Ville(*)</label><input type="text" id="locality" name="ville_adress" style="width:410px" class="fiche" required /> </p>

    <p>
        <label style="width:90px">Etat(*)</label><input type="text" id="administrative_area_level_1" name="etat_adress" style="width:160px" class="fiche" required />
        <label style="width:90px">Code Postal(*)</label><input type="text" id="postal_code" name="code_postal_adress" style="width:157px" class="fiche" required />
    </p>

    <p> <label style="width:90px">Pays(*)</label><input type="text" id="country" name="pays_adress" style="width:410px" class="fiche" required /></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Which uses google map api. I need to render this partial view many times in my view **For example like this**

```
  <div class="tab-content">

   <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_beginplace"> @Html.Partial("_GeoApi")
   </div>

    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_endplace"> @Html.Partial("_GeoApi")
   </div>
 </div>
```

I get this exception :

> you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors

And the autocompletion isn't working since the second partial view rendering.

So I need to know how can I fix this?

Comment: Scripts should never be in partial views. Move them to you view (or layout) so they are only generated once. And change all your controls to use class names (remove the `id` attributes so your not generating invalid html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your scripts should be included only once. This means that you can not have them as a part of a partial view that you want to use multiple times on the same page. You have to put script parts into a separate .js file and render it once.

Also, your partial view should not contain `<html>` and `<body>` tags, it should be partial view, not whole view. You **do not want** the final code to look like this:

```
<html>
 ... main page code ...
   <html>...partial view code 1....</html>
   <html>...partial view code 2....</html>
   <html>...partial view code 3....</html>
</html>
```

That is not a valid HTML document.

And finally, your partial views should not use elements with static id attribute because if you render that twice on the page, your code will have more than one element with the same id, which should be unique ...

**Update:**
In order to replace static IDs with dynamic IDs, you will use a model, in which you pass the information you need. So, instead of having

```
 @Html.Partial("_GeoApi")
```

you will write

```
 @Html.Partial("_GeoApi", model)
```

Then in your partial view code, you will start with

```
 @model MyModel
```

and the passed model will be the instance of MyModel class.

Comment: ok thanks, But the code example required to set the id of each tag https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform and even I try this method to get value by class name it failed

Comment: Yes, you need to use ID, but you do not want to use static ID, because if will not work. You want to use dynamic ID, which means that for each partial view rendering, you will create new ID, so instead of ` id="autocomplete"` in both instances you will have `id="autocomplete1"` in the first instance and `id="autocomplete2"` in the second.

Comment: How can I do that , I mean how can I set a dynamic id to a tag in shared partial view?

Comment: You can do that using a model for that partial view, so instead of `@Html.Partial("_GeoApi")` you will have `@Html.Partial("_GeoApi", model)` and you use that model to pass the information you need - e.g. the view number. See my edit.